# Meteor, Mantra, FlowRouter - Passing more than one parameter to container

Tags: meteor, containers, flow-router

I am trying to pass more than one parameter to Mantra container like this:

```
FlowRouter.route('/cargarDatos/:fechaInicial/:consecutivos', {
name: 'cargarDatos.iniciar',
action({fechaInicial, consecutivos}) {
  mount(MainLayoutCtx, {
    content: () => (<CargarDatos fechaInicial={fechaInicial} consecutivos={consecutivos} />),
    footer: <PiePágina />
  });
}
```

It seems I am doing something wrong since insede CargarDatos container the variables are not recognized. Could somebody help out?

Everything works fine if I only place one parameter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could You place Your container code?

Comment: Thanks @Gemmi, it was an error in container, your inference was correct. And besides, how do I close my own question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax is correct, problem was in container code.